# HP G62 A10SE WiFi Driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, networking

I an trying to figure out what is hardware enclosed in my notebook for wifi access. I can see there is no wifi detected even I have wifi modem. My laptop lacks wifi driver but I am not sure which driver to install for that. I am using Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 different brands of wireless cards that came with that model, you need to figure out which one you have.

1. Intel
2. Ralink (2 different ones, RT3090, RTL8191SE)
3. Broadcom
4. Atheros

see if this utility can identify it  http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

Then download the appropriate driver from here
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4063&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=4199638#N1387

.

.